# Hash#key for 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, hash

Greetings,

I am trying to make my 1.9.1 source 1.8.6 compatible. I recognized that there's no Hash#key method. Any idea or method how to solve that?

Thanks!

Tobias

Answer (score 4):

Use `Hash#index`, or [`require "backports/1.9.1/hash/key"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

You can also `require 'backports'` and most of the API changes from 1.8.6 to 1.9.2 will be backported and available in Ruby 1.8.6 (including `Hash#key`, of course).

Answer (score 2):

In ruby 1.8 that method is called index.

Comment: Ouch, could've seen this. Thanks a lot!